# How do I use the results of a subscription for additional subscriptions at the route level?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a template that displays documents from three different collections `Cars`, `CarPaints`, and `CarPaintTypes`.  I know I need all these upfront at the Router level. The template will show a `Car` document, all the `CarPaints` that reference that `Car`, and all the `CarPaintTypes` that reference the returned `CarPaints` respectively (think nested list). The route to the template takes an `id` from the URL that represents `Car._id`.

Both the `Cars` collection and `CarPaints` collection make use of the `Car._id` as a field (it's the native `_id` of the `Cars` collection and a field in the `CarPaints` collection) so that's easy.  However, the `CarPaintTypes` uses the `CarPaint._id` as a reference to what `CarPaint` it belongs to.

So I have three publications:

```
Meteor.publish('car', function(carId) {
   return Cars.find({_id: carId});
});

Meteor.publish('carPaints', function(carId) {
   return CarPaints.find({carId: carId});
});

Meteor.publish('carPaintTypes', function(carPaintId) {
   return CarPaintTypes.find({carPaintId: carPaintId});
});
```

My route looks like:

```
this.route('car', {
    path: '/car/:_id',

    waitOn: function() {    

        return [Meteor.subscribe('car', this.params._id),
                Meteor.subscribe('carPaints', this.params._id)];
                // Can't figure out how to subscribe to or publish
                // the carPaintTypes using all the results of what gets
                // returned by 'carPaints'
    }   
});
```

My question is `CarPaintTypes` doesn't have the `Car._id` as a field, just the `CarPaint._id` to reference to a `CarPaint` document.  Where and how I do take the results of the subscription to `carPaints` and pass each `carPaint` document that's returned to a subscription to `carPaintTypes`?  Or is there a way to combine them all in the publication?  Is it better to do it later on in my helpers?  I figure since I know what I need at the route level, all the subscription calls should be in the route code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all 3 cursors inside `Meteor.publish` method and simply return them:

```
Meteor.publish('carThings', function(carId){
   var carPaint =  CarPaints.findOne({carId:carId});
   return [
     Cars.find({_id: carId}),
     CarPaints.find({carId: carId}),
     CarPaintTypes.find({carPaintId: carPaint._id});
   ]
})
```

On client:

```
this.route('car', {
    path: '/car/:_id',

    waitOn: function() {    

        return [Meteor.subscribe('carThings', this.params._id)]


    }
}
```

Comment: In your answer you're only finding one `carPaint` document.  What I'm asking is how do I take multiple returned `carPaint` documents and find all the `carPaintTypes` associated to each one of the `carPaint` documents.  The template will end up showing a nested tree with one `Car` at the top, multiple `CarPaints` and multiple `CarPaintTypes` under each `CarPaint`.

Answer (score 0):

With Kuba Wyrobek's help, I figured it out.  For what I was trying to achieve, the publish looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish('carThings', function(carId){
    var carPaints = CarPaints.find({carId: carId}).fetch();
    return [
        Cars.find({_id: carId}),
        CarPaints.find({carId: carId}),
        CarPaintTypes.find({carPaintId: {$in: _.pluck(carPaints, "_id")}})
    ];
});
```

I didn't get that you could do manipulations inside your publication blocks.  This is super cool and flexible.  Thanks for your help.